# SQLAlchemy Reflection Using Metaclass with Column Override

Tags: python-2.7, reflection, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, geoalchemy

I have a set of dynamic database tables (Postgres 9.3 with PostGIS) that I am mapping using a python metaclass:

```
cls = type(str(tablename), (db.Model,), {'__tablename__':tablename})
```

where, db.Model is the db object via flask-sqlalchemy and tablename is a bit of unicode.
The cls is then added to an application wide dictionary `current_app.class_references` (using Flask's current_app) to avoid attempts to instantiate the class multiple times.

Each table contains a geometry column, `wkb_geometry` stored in Well Known Binary.  I want to map these to use [geoalchemy2](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.4/) with the final goal of retrieving GeoJSON.

If I was declaring the table a priori, I would use:

```
class GeoPoly():
    __tablename__ = 'somename'
    wkb_geometry = db.Column(Geometry("POLYGON"))
    #more columns...
```

Since I am trying to do this dynamically, I need to be able to override the reflection of `cls1` with the known type.

### Attempts:

1. Define the column explicitly, using the reflection override syntax.

   ```
   cls = type(str(tablename), (db.Model,), {'__tablename__':tablename,
       'wkb_geometry':db.Column(Geometry("POLYGON"))})
   ```

which returns the following on a fresh restart, i.e. the class has not yet been instantiated:
*InvalidRequestError: Table 'tablename' is already defined for this MetaData instance. Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object*

2. Use mixins with the class defined above (sans **tablename**):

   ```
   cls = type(str(tablename), (GeoPoly, db.Model), {'__tablename__':tablename})
   ```

Again MetaData issues.

3. Override the column definition attribute after the class is instantiated:

   ```
   cls = type(str(tablename), (db.Model,), {'__tablename__':tablename})
   current_app.class_references[tablename] = cls
   cls.wkb_geometry = db.Column(Geometry("POLYGON"))
   ```

Which results in:

*InvalidRequestError: Implicitly combining column tablename.wkb_geometry with column tablename.wkb_geometry under attribute 'wkb_geometry'. Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly.*

Is it possible to use the metadata construction to support dynamic reflection **and* *override a column known will be available on all tables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I exactly follow what you're doing, but I've overridden reflected columns in the past inside my own `__init__`  method on a custom metaclass that inherits from `DeclarativeMeta`.  Any time the new base class is used, it checks for a 'wkb_geometry' column name, and replaces it with (a copy of) the one you created.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta, declarative_base

wkb_geometry = db.Column(Geometry("POLYGON"))

class MyMeta(DeclarativeMeta):
    def __init__(cls, clsname, parents, dct):
        for key, val in dct.iteritems():
            if isinstance(sa.Column) and key is 'wkb_geometry':
                dct[key] = wkb_geometry.copy()

MyBase = declarative_base(metaclass=MyMeta)

cls = type(str(tablename), (MyBase,), {'__tablename__':tablename})
```

This may not exactly work for you, but it's an idea. You probably need to add `db.Model` to the `MyBase` tuple, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to customize a particular column while relying on `autoload` for everything else. The code below assumes an existing declarative `Base` object for a table named `my_table`. It loads the metadata for all columns but overrides the definition of a column named `polygon`:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    __table_args__ = (Column(name='polygon', type=Geometry("POLYGON"),
                      {'autoload':True})
```

Other arguments to the [`Table`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) constructor can be provided in the dictionary. Note that the dictionary must appear last in the list!

The SQLAlchemy documentation [Using a Hybrid Approach with `__table__`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table) provides more details and examples.